# Android: weird appearance of the action bar after action mode closing

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, android-actionmode, multichoiceitems

I've discovered a strange problem while try to implement `ListView` with multichoice mode. I use `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` to turn on multichoice mode, and `MultiChoiceModeListener` to provide action mode menu and handle events. Here is my code:

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item,
            new String[] {"111", "222", "333", "444", "555"});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu); // my_menu is just stub empty menu
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }
    });
```

It works fine, I can select my list items and action mode appears: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ3Nx.png). The problem is that when I **rotate my device** and then **close action mode** by pressing back button, sometimes (not every time) the action bar becomes ugly, with strange light background: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/man6H.png)

It is reproducing on my device with Android 5.0. The code is quite easy, and I don't think that it is bug in my code. Maybe, it is internal bug in Android system? Did anyone face this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should force the `ActionBar` to redraw itself. Check my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997778/3185295