# ActionBar changes colour after changing phone orientation and closing Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

### Problem

First my ActionBar (with custom menu) is purple, then:

1. Trigger CAB by long-click on my ListView
2. Change phone orientation
3. Cancel CAB

ActionBar becomes white. This does not happen without phone orientation change. I have tried this on android `4.4.4`, `minSdkVersion="19"`, `targetSdkVersion="26"`. Can you please advise me, why this could happen?

**UPDATE:** Tried on API 25 emulator, and this does not happen.

---

### Sources

Activity layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="sk.tuke.smart.makac.activities.FreeShootingHistoryActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_freeshootinghistory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_activated_2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`switch_menu.xml` - classic Action Bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item_switchmenu_label"
        android:title="@string/switchmenu_colouring"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_switchmenu_switch"
        android:title="@string/switchmenu_colouring"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

`delete_menu.xml` - Contextual Action Bar:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_deletemenu_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
        android:title="@string/deletemenu_delete" />
</menu>
```

initializing ActionBar in activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.switch_menu, menu);
    //...stuff...

    return true;
}
```

setting up CAB in `onCreate()`:

```
historyListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
historyListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(choiceModeListener);
```

inside `MultiChoiceModeListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu for the CAB
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu);

    //...stuff...

    return true;
}
```

in `<application>` inside Manifest this style is set `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#8600b3</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#730099</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#bfc6f6</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_secondary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue exists on Lollipop with a slightly different result. In my case the support `ActionBar` just gets darker with little 'shadows' on both sides.

The following hack works on all API versions:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    // Find the ActionBar view
    final View view = findActionBarView(
            mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView());

    if (view != null) {
        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Start view animation
                view.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100);
            }
        });
    }
}

public static ViewGroup findActionBarView(View view) {
    try {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

            // You can search for the Toolbar if necessary
            if (viewGroup instanceof android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer) {
                for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View actionView = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

                    // Return currently visible context bar
                    if (actionView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        return (ViewGroup) actionView;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ViewGroup actionView =
                        getActionBarView(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));

                if (actionView != null) {
                    return actionView;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "View not found", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

P.S. Basically, you just have to perform any simple animation on the `ActionBar` view. If you find the root of the problem in the source code, or maybe more elegant way to fix it, please let me know.